# Bad thread access/seg fault QuickSort

Tags: c++

I'm working on a sorting project and my quick sort works just fine with 300kb of data, but when i try to sort 1mb of data, program gives me bad thread access in Xcode and seg fault:11 in terminal.

```
 void SortingCompetition::quicksort(int low, int high)
{
if (high!=low&& high>low)
{

long one=hash[low];
long two=hash[high];
long three = hash[high/2];
    if((one<=two&&one>=three)||(one<=three&&one>=two))
    {
        swap(hash[low], hash[high]);
        swap(copyOfWords[low], copyOfWords[high]);
    }
    else if((three<=one&&three>=two)||(three<=two&&three>=one))
    {

        swap(hash[high/2], hash[high]);
        swap(copyOfWords[high/2], copyOfWords[high]);
    }
    else
    {

    }
    int i=low;
    int j=high-1;
    while(i!=j&&i<j)
    {
        while(hash[i]<=hash[high]&&i<j)
        {
            i++;
        }
        while(hash[j]>=hash[high]&&i<j)
        {
            j--;
        }
        if(i==j||i>j)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            swap(hash[i],hash[j]);
            swap(copyOfWords[i],copyOfWords[j]);
                        }
        }
    swap(hash[i],hash[high]);
    swap(copyOfWords[i], copyOfWords[high]);
    quicksort(low, j-1);
    quicksort(j+1, high);
}
```

both hash and copyofwords are dynamically allocated to the same size. I don't know how to fix this problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a recursive method. So you are overflowing the stack with the calls.

Whenever you call a function, including recursively, the return address and often the arguments are pushed onto the call stack. The stack is finite, so if the recursion is too deep you'll eventually run out of stack space.

Comment: is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: You can translate it to iterative algorithm. Every recursive algorithm can be expresed in interative mode.

Comment: Thanks, there was something wrong with my compiler and I researched iterative, but haven't had time to implement it.